# Perl - add a variable in a variable

Tags: perl, variables

I want add the variable `$hostname` in the variable `$hostame_table` appended with `_table`.

My code:

```
use Sys::Hostname ();
my $hostname = Sys::Hostname::hostname();
my $hostname_table = "$hostname"+"_table";
print "$hostname_table";
```

I would like the result to be `computername_table`.

Comment: From [perlop](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Additive-Operators): Binary `"+"` returns the sum of two numbers. Binary `"."` concatenates two strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for here is called "string concatenation". Perl uses a dot (`.`) as the concatenation operator, not the `+` which you've tried to use.

```
$hostname_table = $hostname . '_table';
print $hostname_table;
```

**Update:** Another common approach would be to just "interpolate" the values in a double-quoted string.

```
$hostname_table = "$hostname_table"; # This doesn't work.
```

Unfortunately, this simple approach doesn't work here as "_table" is valid as part of a variable name and, therefore, Perl doesn't know where your variable name ends. You can get around that by using a slightly more complex syntax which wraps the variable name in `{ ... }`.

```
$hostname_table = "${hostname}_table";
```

Comment: Perhaps throw in a blurb about interpolation as well (I was going to but you've already got the first part done): `my $hostname_table = "${hostname}_table";`

Comment: @stevieb: I considered it, but the need for `{...}` in this case made it slightly more complicated than I wanted to explain. I'll give it a go :-/

Comment: You don't have to, it was just a thought ;)

Comment: @stevieb: Done.

Comment: ++. I just thought it would round out the answer is all.